# I want to replace a date value per employee

Tags: python, sql, replace, databricks

​I have this file in excel. I need to do the transformation on it. For a particular Personnum and for a particular date, I want to check if the ENDREASON is out or missedOut. If it is missedOut then the date ENDDTM of the previous entry. i.e the last out entry will be considered as the StartDTM for missedOut value. Is there any way I can code it in python or SQL? Any way I can do it in Databricks?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no column called out I think we will have to use a rank function and then play around with the query. I have not tested the query something similar to below should work .Please do focus on the rank function which I am using and adding 1 to the second query.

```
CREATE TABLE foo1 
(
    APPLYDATE datetime,
    STARTDTM datetime,
    ENDDTM datetime,
    PERSONNUM int,
    STARTREASON varchar(100),
    ENDREASON varchar(100) 
) 

select getdate()

INSERT INTO foo1 
VALUES ('2020-04-23 00:00:00.000','2020-04-23 06:30:47.223','2020-04-23 10:10:47.223',204901477,'newshift','out')
INSERT INTO foo1 
VALUES ('2020-04-23 00:00:00.000','2020-04-23 21:45:47.223','2020-04-23 21:45:47.223',204901477,'newshift','missedout')
INSERT INTO foo1 
VALUES ('2020-04-23 00:00:00.000','2020-04-23 10:10:47.223','2020-04-23 12:15:47.223',204901477,'newshift','out')

INSERT INTO foo1 
VALUES ('2020-04-24 00:00:00.000','2020-04-24 06:30:47.223','2020-04-24 10:10:47.223',204901478,'newshift','out')
INSERT INTO foo1 
VALUES ('2020-04-24 00:00:00.000','2020-04-24 21:45:47.223','2020-04-24 21:45:47.223',204901478,'newshift','missedout')
INSERT INTO foo1 
VALUES ('2020-04-24 00:00:00.000','2020-04-24 10:10:47.223','2020-04-24 12:15:47.223',204901478,'newshift','out')


SELECT
    aa.PERSONNUM,
    ENDDTM = CASE 
                WHEN aa.ENDREASON = 'missedout' THEN bb.ENDDTM
                ELSE aa.ENDDTM
             END
FROM
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONNUM ORDER BY PERSONNUM) AS id1,
         *
     FROM
         foo1) aa 
JOIN 
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONNUM ORDER BY PERSONNUM) + 1  AS id2,
         *
     FROM
         foo1) bb ON aa.id1 = bb.id2
```